# criar matriz através de um arquivo em python

Tags: python

Sou iniciante em python, e estou tentando criar um código para exibir informações de login, em um arquivo de texto as informações estão salvas assim: 13:30, gabriel santana, 12345678
no caso o que é salvo no arquivo é a hora do login, nome do user, e o respectivo número dele, porem quando tento transformar em matriz através deste código:

```
arquivo = open('arquivo.txt', 'r')
linha = {}
linha = arquivo.readline()
print(linha[0])
```

a intenção com o **linha[0]** era printar a hora e se fosse **linha[1]** printar o nome, porém o que é mostrado é o caracter da ordem definida entre os []

Comment: Favor atualizar o post com parte do conteúdo do `arquivo.txt`

Comment: no arquivo esta salvo assim: 13:30, gabriel santana, 12345678

Answer (score 1):

Algumas questões com seu código.

```
arquivo = open('arquivo.txt', 'r') # 1
linha = {}                         # 2
linha = arquivo.readline()         # 3
print(linha[0])                    # 4
```

### Nota #1

Esta linha está OK

### Nota #2

Esta linha não tem motivo de estar aqui, pois imediatamente abaixo, você reinicializa a variável `linha`

### Nota #3

Este comando lê apenas uma linha, sendo assim, deveria estar dentro de um laço de repetição.

### Nota #4

`linha` é uma variável do tipo `str` (String), sendo assim o índice 0 (zero) é o primeiro caracter da string.

## Alternativas

### Usar o readlines()

```
arquivo = open('arquivo.txt', 'r')
linhas = arquivo.readlines()
arquivo.close()   # 5

for linha in linhas:
    campos = linha.replace("\n", "").split(",")  # 6
    print(campos[0], campos[1], campos[2])
```

### Usar o readline() dentro de um laço de repetição

```
arquivo = open('arquivo.txt', 'r')
linha = arquivo.readline()

while linha:
    linha = linha.replace("\n", "")
    campos = linha.split(",")
    print(campos[0], campos[1], campos[2])
    linha = arquivo.readline()

arquivo.close()
```

### Nota #5

Usando esta forma, não esqueça de fechar o arquivo

### Nota #6

Tem que fazer o `replace("\n","")` para substituir as quebras de linha por vazio e usar o `split(",")` para separar a string em itens de uma lista

## Forma mais correta de ler um arquivo

```
with open('arquivo.txt', 'r') as arquivo:
    # processa o arquivo aqui.
```

Assim, o próprio Python se encarrega de fechar o arquivo, caso tenha algum problema "no meio do caminho"

Outra maneira seria:

```
linhas = open('arquivo.txt', 'r').readlines()
```

Sendo um arquivo com linhas separadas por vírgula, ou seja, um arquivo CSV. Sugiro dar uma lida sobre a biblioteca `csv` do Python [aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).